# How to prove that $f_X(x) = (1-p)^xp$ is a probability function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### Exercise:

> An experiment is performed where an event A (success) with probability
>   p, or no occurrence (failure) can occur, with probability 1 - p, where
>   p ∈ (0, 1). In successive repetitions of the same experiment it will
>   be assumed that the probability p is kept constant in each of them
>   and, in addition, that they are independent.
>
> Consider the discrete random variable X, defined as the "number of
>   failures before obtaining the first success in successive
>   experiments".
>
> a) What is the range of this random variable?
>
> b) Deduce the analytic expression of the probability function of this
>   random variable.
>
> c) Show that the function obtained in b, is indeed a probability
>   function.
>
> Note: Any discrete random variable, with the above probability
>   function, is called the Geometric random variable, of parameter p, and
>   is represented by X ~ G (p).

### Solution:

- a) $R_X = {0,1,2,3,...}$
- b) $f_X(x) = (1-p)^xp$
- c) ?

Comment: You need to show that $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (1-p)^kp = 1 $$

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that was a typo. Whoops. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f_X$ is nonnegative and its mass is $\sum_{x=0}^\infty f_X(x)=p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=1$ (I've used the geometric series in the first equality) so $f_X$ is indeed a probability function.

Comment: You said "so $f_X$ is indeed a probability function". Does that mean you've proven it?

Comment: @CarlosFrostte Yes, in order to check that $f_X$ is a probability function you need to verify two things: that $f_X(x)\geq0$ for every $x$ (which I only asserted at the beginning since in this case it is trivial), and that its mass (i.e. the sum of $f_X(x)$ over $x$) is $1$ (which I calculated in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

It should satisfy the following axioms:

1) $P(X=x)\ge 0$. $\to (1-p)^xp>0$ for all $x = 0,1,2,3...$

2) $P(\Omega)=1$. $\to P(\Omega) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^xp = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)}=1$.

Where the last step followed from a sum of infinite geometric series.